# phpmailer attaching two pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer for attaching pdf files and sending email with pdf attachments. One pdf file is being attached while the other is not being attached.
I am using the code as

```
$attachedfile = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form_test.pdf';
$mail->addAttachment($attachedfile, 'Visa Application'); 
$attachedfile2 = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form.pdf';
$mail->addAttachment($attachedfile2, 'Visa Application 2');
```

Only one pdf file is being attached other one is being attached.
It also works with single pdf file attatchment. 
I have also use the following code

`$attachedfile = array($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form.pdf',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_test.pdf');
foreach($attachedfile as $attachment){
  $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
}`

But again it attachs one pdf file

please help

Comment: Check the return value of each call to `addAttachment` to be sure your script is able to read the files.

Comment: One file is returning 1 and other is nothing

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that PHP returns 1 and nothing for the two calls to `addAttachment`. That's what PHP uses as text representation of `true` and `false`: One of your files is not readable by PHP, because the file is missing, the path is wrong, or it lacks sufficient ownership or permission. Double-check your paths and permissions.

When I say don't build your paths, I mean use *only* literal strings for the paths. You can write a standalone PHP script to check them:

```
<?php
$path1 = '/var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form_test.pdf';
$path2 = '/var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form.pdf';
var_dump($path1, is_file($path1), $path2, is_file($path2));
```

Check them in your shell too:

```
ls -al /var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form_test.pdf /var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form.pdf
```

If those are OK, go back to your original script and `var_dump` your generated paths, and compare them - including the length, in case you've accidentally included some non-printing or zero-width chars.

Comment: I have checked both files are with in same directory and same path. Both have the same path and permissions :(

Comment: I have also renamed and copy paste the same file. it still show the single attachment.

Comment: [Look at the code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L2776): the only way that `addAttachment` returns `false` is if `is_file()` returns false. Check your paths again - use hard-coded path strings to test with, don't build them. If you set `$mail->exceptions = true`, you should get an exception about it.

Comment: While the pdf file is in the directory.

Comment: Permission set is 0644

Comment: Check your paths, check your paths, and then check them again... You could write a separate PHP script just to confirm them, see revised notes in my answer.

Comment: `string(124) "/home4/xyz/public_html/xyz.net/dev/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form_test.pdf" bool(false) 
string(119) "/home4/xyz/public_html/xyz.net/dev/wp-content/plugins/xyz-user-registration/images/iraq_visa_form.pdf" bool(true)`
but physically both pdf files are there is same directory/folder

Comment: But when I browse directly file on browser it works and pdf file shows on browser

Comment: A browser will only use the path relative to the doc root. What happened with the shell test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170981/discussion-between-ali-and-synchro).